# .OTF font not being deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an MVC 4 application with an .otf font in the /images folder. It works on my desktop, but when I deploy to azure I get a 404 when trying to access /images/myfont.otf

The font already has the Build Action property set to 'Content'

How can I force Azure to pick this up?

Comment: You can confirm whether the file gets copied by extracting the **cspkg** file (this is what gets uploaded to Azure), you can find it in `X:\Solution\AzureProject\bin\ConfigName\app.publish\AzureProject.cspkg` You'll need to extract your ASP.NET project then check the Content folder under sitesroot.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You probably need to configure the IIS to properly serve this file type. You do this by adding the following to the `<system.webServer>` element in `Web.config`:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
</staticContent>
```

More info
http://www.big.info/2013/06/how-to-use-otf-opentype-format-fonts-on.html

Comment: here in .NET6 you don't have the `web.config` file on the solution, but you can find the file connecting to FTP server

Comment: @AntonioCorreia You can still have a Web.config if you want/need it. If you just change the file on the server, that file can be lost together with your changes. This is not a recommended way.

Answer (score 9):

Place the following in `web.config` in the `system.webServer` configuration:

```
<system.webServer>    
   <staticContent>
       <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
       <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTTP Error 404 means the content is not found on server. It does mean that when you deploy your application to Windows Azure the content was not in the package.

As you suggested above that you do have .OTF set as content it means that you are asking compiler to treat it as static file and don't build it however specific file will not be copied to the final output folder to be the part of final CSPKG. You would need to set "Copy to output directory" as "copy always" so it can be part of CSPKG and deployed to Azure Cloud service.

Once you set file properties correctly and build your application, you can manually visit to your output folder to the verify that file is there as well as your CSPKG just by unzipping it.

[image]

Comment: This is probably not the issue. A font file is no different from say an image, and you never need to change any property for those. See my answer for a more probable cause.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me is that the files weren't included with the project. They were in the correct file path (`(project)/Content/fonts/*`), but not considered part of the project (i.e. references by the `*.csproj` file). The solution was to right click the fonts folder and choose the `Include in Project` option.

Answer (score -1):

My best bet is that you've got relative paths to your font files within your css.

Are you getting a 403 Forbidden? That might indicate that your filepath's are off.

Try changing your paths from ../filename.otf to something like /Styles/filename.otf (or whatever your path is)